# How to solve this 403 Forbidden?

Tags: angularjs, laravel, .htaccess, amazon-s3, server

> i am trying to play video on chrome browser but when page is loaded. even video thumbnail is loaded but video does not play. 
>   i got below status code `403 Forbidden`

Why this has happened, can anyone help me to solve this?

Here is video url is being accessed in html.

```
<div class="item-wrapper">
    <div class="media-content">
        <video class="video-js vjs-default-skin"   id="play" controls preload="auto" poster="{{vm.media.assets[0].thumbnails[2].url }}">
            <source src="{{vm.media.trustedUrl}}" type="video/mp4" />
        </video>
    </div>
</div>
```

Request URL

```
Request URL: https://d5pdtgresjcn6.cloudfront.net/c02b5addd79479d63d7b12f1648f1b94.mp4?t=18b70468094a46c37d5e9aafcf96ef35&Expires=1902381651&Signature=KZG4RHiEwg-3-PFST2QWmRjG1ddT5m4o~5vDiNzmBb5iXxrsm7Ocx7TbZxMH1prZa6wq2lmnw1p3Nr0fg4zr4CZvh9oFnSRkOaiaeO36BkNAyv8x~xHpEQRI204FLTkUcnpsuvY~0ptPY89g-1FYkg6WOr7PWoZktnPUvg9xjSlGhe8WlO8Of4gM7wIBw1VGtr5kufuEt5fKsO6FILX3nc1AF-jklTqT-VCMTD6SI30JYDPOPHEFtWrK-022Sac0sGMaABVJy~54Qb76LfDI0rLkODjmzP8Tc5S1ZK7S2JRgV3-rLZsnLTudHKJbJ3CQGoLWDKdzag8~ci9ccRbNNw__&Key-Pair-Id=APKAIFZZLEFBSXLAPPQA
```

[image]

Comment: It appears that the traffic is being served from Amazon CloudFront via a Pre-Signed URL. Is this correct? Please Edit your question to provide more details about how you are serving the content, what permissions you have granted, how the signed URL was created and how the video is being accessed in your HTML page (code please!). Please add these details to the question, rather than adding as a comment.

Comment: Your video file permission is allowed?

Comment: @A.A Noman, Thank you. Permission is allowed

Comment: @JohnRotenstein, can you help me to solve this plz?

Comment: Can you tell us how your app is generating the `trustedUrl`? That is the part that appears to be failing. Is the video meant to be public to everyone, or is it intentionally private?